# How to bulk delete docs from elasticsearch using php

Tags: php, elasticsearch, bigdata

I am having the following code to delete the docs from elasticsearch .

```
public function deleteByQuery(){

    $client = $this->_connectElasticSearchClient();
    $params = [
       'index' => $this->_indexName,
       'type' => $this->_typeName,
       'body' => [
           'query' => [
               'match' => [
                   'brand' => 'apple'
               ]
           ]
       ]
    ];
    $response = $client->deleteByQuery($params);
    print_r($response);die;
 }
```

I am getting the following as response.

```
{
  "found": false,
  "_index": "gadgets",
  "_type": "products",
  "_id": "_query",
  "_version": 1,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

Tried changing the query string and all.but no use. While searching with the above query ,I am getting data also.

I am using Elasticsearch-PHP Client.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: {
  "name" : "Rachel Summers",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "72cd1f1a3eee09505e036106146dc1949dc5dc87",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-11-18T22:40:03Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Elasticsearch 2.1, you need to know that the delete-by-query feature has been [removed from the core](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_delete_by_query_is_now_a_plugin) and [moved into a dedicated plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.1/plugins-delete-by-query.html).

You need to install that plugin first in order for your PHP code to work.

```
./bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```